# T-SQL to get View Column Definition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've found numerous places that have similarities but none that actually come close to what I'm looking for, that being getting the actual definition of a view's individual columns (vs the full view definition).

Given the following example, I'm trying to get the definition of each of the view's columns separately.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_TABLE]
(
    [id] int NOT NULL,
    [created] datetime NULL,
    [counts] int NULL,
    [url] varchar(20) NULL
);
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TEST_VIEW]
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT [id] AS [id]
    , CONVERT( varchar(16), [created], 107 ) AS [created]
    , CONVERT( varchar(20), [counts] ) + ' - ' + [url] AS [url]
    FROM [dbo].[TEST_TABLE];
GO

DROP VIEW [dbo].[TEST_VIEW];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[TEST_TABLE];
GO
```

The result I'm looking for is something akin to this:

```
name    definition
------- ------------------------------------------------
id      [id]
created CONVERT( varchar(16), [created], 107 )
url     CONVERT( varchar(20), [counts] ) + ' - ' + [url]
```

Any help in getting closer to this would be highly appreciated as I've been struggling with this all day already.  I can get the full view definition but the columns can be quite a mess to try get out:

```
SELECT sysmod.definition AS [View Definition]
FROM sys.sql_modules sysmod
INNER JOIN sys.objects sysob ON ( sysmod.object_id = sysob.object_id )
INNER JOIN sys.schemas syssh ON ( sysobj.schema_id = syssch.schema_id )
WHERE sysob.name = N'TEST_VIEW'
AND syssh.name = N'dbo';
```

Something like `sys.computed_columns` but for views would have been absolutely perfect.

Comment: Good Question But I dont think its possible. Eg: If there is a join on the table and you are taking the primary key in that case you will define a.PrimaryKey so it will make complex.. There will be someone who can simplyfy for it.

Comment: As far as I am aware this is not possible, as it would be ambiguous. For example, what would you expect to see if your view contains a `UNION`? e.g. `CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT 10 + 1 AS ID UNION ALL SELECT 10 - 1 AS ID`. Should the definition for ID be `10 + 1` or `10 - 1`?

Comment: @GarethD: Such an awesome example, I had clearly missed that in my attempt to define the requirement, while it doesn't give me what I need, it sure does disambiguate the issue and gives me something to work with.  I had pre-empted joins and such but didn't think of unions.  Thanks!